# Bash script to verify if a process is running is not working

Tags: bash, process, administrator

I have a simple script as below which checks if [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org) service is running or not on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to check if fail2ban service is running

if pgrep -x "fail2ban" > /dev/null
then
   echo "Fail2ban is running"
else
   echo "Fail2ban is not running"
fi
```

I have installed fail2ban in a test VM and is running on the VM. [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3b79.png) of `systemctl status` command.

But, when the run the above script, I get the result that "Fail2ban is not running". I am not sure if is with the script. I tried `ps aux` command too instead of `pgrep`. But, [I still get the same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxAXH.png).

Comment: Why even try to cobble something together with `ps`, when you can use `systemctl is-active fail2ban`? FWIW your command probably fails because you specified an exact match (`-x`) but the process name is actually `fail2ban.server`

Comment: Ok. Thanks. It worked, I changed the command to the above command. But, is there any way you know why pgrep will not work? Also, Is systemctl command available by default in all redhat systems?

Comment: @steeldriver That's the _service_ name, not the _process_ name.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit my mistake, the process is `fail2ban-server` (with a hyphen); `pgrep -x fail2ban.server` finds it because it's a regex match (`.` matches the `-`) and for example `systemctl status fail2ban.service` says `Main PID: 2721 (fail2ban-server)`. The *service* name is fail2ban.serv**ice** I believe.

Comment: @steeldriver Nope, fail2ban is a Python script. The process is `/usr/bin/python3`.

Answer (score 13):

You asked `pgrep` to exactly (`-x`) search for a process called `fail2ban`
but the output of `systemctl status` shows it is called 
`/usr/bin/python3` instead.

To check whether a `systemd` unit is running use

```
systemctl is-active --quiet fail2ban
```

That is:

```
if systemctl is-active --quiet fail2ban; then
    echo "running"
else
    echo "not running"
fi
```

Comment: Alternatively, one could use `pgrep -f '*fail2ban*'` to pattern-match or `pgrep -f '/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/fail2ban-server'` to match exactly what screenshots reveal

Comment: `pgrep -f '*fail2ban*'` could catch the `pgrep` command itself.

Comment: At least on my 16.04 system, in spite of it being a python script, the process name (as seen in `/proc/<pid>/comm`) is `fail2ban-server` so `pgrep -x fail2ban-server` does work - although I see no reason to use it when `systemctl is-active` is available

Answer (score 1):

The following shellscript `running` combines the result of

- `systemctl is-active` and
- `ps -ef | ... | grep`

in order to detect if a certain program (or a program name containing the search string) is running or not.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
 echo "Usage:    $0 <program-name>
          $0 <part of program name>
Examples: $0 firefox
          $0 term
          $0 dbus
          $0 'dbus-daemon --session'"
 exit
fi

inversvid="\0033[7m"
resetvid="\0033[0m"
redback="\0033[1;37;41m"
greenback="\0033[1;37;42m"
blueback="\0033[1;37;44m"

runn=false
tmpfil=$(mktemp)

# check by systemctl

systemctl is-active --quiet "$1"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
 echo "systemctl is-active:"
 runn=true
fi

# check by ps

ps -ef | tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 8-9 | grep "$1" | grep -vE -e "$0 $1" -e "grep $1" | sort -u > "$tmpfil"

tmpstr=$(head -n1 $tmpfil)
#echo "$tmpstr"
if [ "$tmpstr" == "$1" ] || [ "${tmpstr##*/}" == "$1" ] || [ "${1##*/}" == "${0##*/}" ]
then
 echo "ps -ef: active:"
 runn=true
elif test -s "$tmpfil"
then
 if $runn
 then
  echo "----- consider also ---------------------------------------------"
  cat "$tmpfil"
  echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------"
 else
  echo "----- try with: -------------------------------------------------"
  cat "$tmpfil"
  echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------"
 fi
fi

if $runn
then
 echo -e "$greenback $1 is running $resetvid"
else
 inpath=$(which "$1")
 if [ "$inpath" == "" ]
 then
  echo -e "$redback no path found to $1 $resetvid"
 else
  echo -e "$blueback $1 is not running $resetvid"
 fi
fi
```

Make it executable and put it in a directory in PATH, if you wish. I put it into my `bin` directory and can used it without any path.

Usage:

```
$ running 
Usage:    /home/sudodus/bin/running <program-name>
          /home/sudodus/bin/running <part of program name>
Examples: /home/sudodus/bin/running firefox
          /home/sudodus/bin/running term
          /home/sudodus/bin/running dbus
          /home/sudodus/bin/running 'dbus-daemon --session'
```

Examples:

```
$ running firefox
ps -ef: active:
 firefox is running   # green background - running

$ running term
----- try with: -------------------------------------------------
/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
xterm
x-terminal-emulator
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 no path found to term   # red background - path not found

$ running dbus
systemctl is-active:
----- consider also ---------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session
/usr/bin/dbus-daemon --syslog
/usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system
/usr/bin/fcitx-dbus-watcher unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-Nm2MSvuTZF,guid=25bad8d51276d088045625055c425080
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 dbus is running   # green background

$ running 'dbus-daemon --session'
ps -ef: active:
 dbus-daemon --session is running   # green background

$ running libreoffice
 libreoffice is not running    # blue background - not running
```